# Button alignment when text box shrinks (CSS)

Tags: html, css

Alright, what I am trying to do is, I want the button beside my text box to be aligned beside the text box whenever my page resize, which would cause my text box to shrink or expand accordingly ( as you can see below in the following snippet) Can someone help me out here? Thanks in advance for the help!

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
```

```css
.topnav {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.topnav a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.hehe {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.topnav a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: skyblue;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .topnav a:not(:nth-child(-n+2)),
  .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a:not(:nth-child(-n+2)),
  .hehe {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {
    float: none;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .hehe {
    float: none;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .hehe {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}


.searchFeature {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 3px 18px 3px 4px;     /* Use the same right padding (18) in jQ! */
  border-radius: 3px;
  /* transition: background 0.4s; */
  width:40%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 18px;
  left: 75px;
}

.test {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav" ng-controller="searchController">
          <a href="#!/index" class="searchba"><img ng-src="" />LOGO</a>
          <input type="text" class="searchFeature" ng-model="selected" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 && searchFunction()" uib-typeahead="value for value in themename | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:7" placeholder="Start your search here..."><button class="test">Test</button>
        <div class="hehe">
          <a href="">Developer</a>
          <a href="">Data Enquiry</a>
        </div>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">Categories <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
            <div class="dropdown-content" >
              <a ng-click="pickCate(x)" ng-repeat="x in selectCate">{{ x }}</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove absolute positioning from both `.test` and `.searchFeature`, then wrap them in a flexbox. I also recommend adding a min-width to the input.

HTML:

```
<div class="search-wrapper">
  <input type="text" class="searchFeature" ng-model="selected" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 && searchFunction()" uib-typeahead="value for value in themename | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:7" placeholder="Start your search here...">
  <button class="test">Test</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.search-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.test {}

.searchFeature {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 3px 18px 3px 4px; /* Use the same right padding (18) in jQ! */
  border-radius: 3px;
  /* transition: background 0.4s; */
  width:40%;
}
```